# How to find element id using click event listener in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, addeventlistener

I am using puppeteer to listen to click events. I would also like to know the id of the html element clicked. How can I do so? My code right now is as follows:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
let page = await browser.newPage();
// Expose a handler to the page
  await page.exposeFunction('onClick', ({ type, detail }) => {
    console.log(`Event fired: ${type}, detail: ${detail}`);
});

// listen for events of type 'status' and
// pass 'type' and 'detail' attributes to our exposed function
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener('click', ({ type, detail }) => {
        window.onClick({ type, detail });
    });
});

await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/login");

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

When adding an event listener, in the callback function, you can access the `event` parameter, and subsequently access the event's `target` to get the element that triggered the event. You can access the element's properties like id, class, etc. so your window's `onClick` event listener's callback should go something like this

```
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.getAttribute("id"));
    });
```